# Is there an operation update(key) = Option(Value) in scala.Map?

Tags: scala, dictionary, option-type

You use either `update(key) = value` or `remove(key)` operations to update a `Map`. But can you embed desired operation in the value? This is what I currently do:

```
map.update(key) = {
  case Some(value) => map += key -> value
  case None => map -= key
}
```

Can I simply write `map(key) = option`?

Comment: Do you mean `map(key) = { ... }` or `map.update(key, { ... })` in your example?  You are using a mutable `Map`?

Comment: @BenReich I think that I can use the mutable but not necessarily. AFAIK map(key) = value is desugared into map.update(key, value).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly:

- if the option has a value (`Some(value)`), you want to add the value to the map (with key `key`)
- if the option has no value (`None`), you want to remove the key `key` from the map

It think this could be done with:

```
val newMap = option.map(value => map + key -> value).getOrElse(map - key)
```

If you use a mutable map, this will return a new map and will not update the `map` value.